# how to use ngIf with ngFor to limit items to appear

Tags: angular, indexing, limit, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have this code in `angular`

````
``` 
        <div *ngFor ="let product of category?.products; let i=index" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-1 mix {{ 'cat-' + category?.id }}">
                <div *ngIf="i<2">
                    <app-item-product[product]="product"></app-item-product>
                </div>
        </div>
```
````

and i need to show 2 result but its show all the products

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice`

```
<div *ngFor ="let product of (category?.products | slice:0:2); let i=index" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-1 mix {{ 'cat-' + category?.id }}">
                <app-item-product[product]="product"></app-item-product>
    </div>
```

Comment: not working actually i don't understand why this happened

Answer (score 0):

```
show_more = false;

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];    


<button (click)="show_more = !show_more">
  <div>{{ show_more ? 'show less' : 'show more...' }}</div>
</button>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content" *ngFor="let x of arr; let i = index">
     <div *ngIf="i < 2 || show_more">
        {{ x }}
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a stackblitz example, check it out [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7im4cx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Answer (score 0):

Simply slice your array.

```js
<div *ngFor ="let product of category!.products.slice(0, 2); let i=index">
  <div>
    <app-item-product[product]="product"></app-item-product>
  </div>
</div>
```